# Lipschitz Homeomorphism and $\mathcal{l_p}$ spaces

Tags: real-analysis, hilbert-spaces

While solving a homework that asked me to find two metric spaces that are not lipschitz homeomorphic it crossed my mind the question (assuming to have in $\mathcal{l^n}$ the metric $|x|$=$\sqrt[n]{\sum(x_i)^n}$):

*If $p\ne n$ then $\mathcal{l^p}$ is not lipschitz-homeomorphic to $\mathcal{l^n}$*?

Here $\mathcal{l}$  means the "sequence space" and with the power $p$ I mean that $x_i\in\mathcal{l^p}$ implies $\sum(x_i)^p<\infty$.

I suspect this to be false in this specific metric, if so, is there a norm that makes the question true?

Comment: I'd take a one-point space and a two-point space... way easier than Lipschitz equivalence of Banach spaces.

Comment: Or, real line and the cusp $y = \sqrt{|x|}$, if you want an example of two homeomorphic metric spaces that are not Lipschitz homeomorphic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true that the $\ell^p$ and $\ell^q$, $p\ne q$, are not Lipschitz homeomorphic. (And changing a norm to an equivalent one does not change this.) This fact is not something that can be proved with bare hands, unless one of $p,q$ is $\infty$, when separability makes the distinction clear. Chapter 7 of [Geometric Nonlinear Functional Analysis](https://books.google.com/books/about/Geometric_Nonlinear_Functional_Analysis.html?id=lXZ95EKwjYUC) by Benyamini and Lindenstrauss establishes this result  by linearizing Lipschitz maps using a kind of Rademacher's differentiation theorem:

1. A Lipschitz map $F$ between $\ell^p$ and $\ell^q$ ($1\le p,q<\infty$) is Gateaux differentiable a.e.
2. If $F$ is bi-Lipschitz, then its derivative is an embedding (but not necessarily an isomorphism).
3. Therefore, if $\ell^p$ and $\ell^q$ are Bi-Lipschitz equivalent, then each of them embeds into the other one.
4. The linear theory (*type* and *cotype* of Banach spaces) then completes the investigation. If two spaces embed into each other, they must have the same type and the same cotype. For finite $p$, the space $\ell^p$ has type $\min(p,2)$ and cotype $\max(p,2)$; therefore, the type-cotype pair determines $p$.

A different approach was recently made possible by *metric cotype* introduced by Mendel and Naor, together with the notion of *Enflo type* that was around for longer. These are bi-Lipschitz invariants of metric spaces; and for Banach spaces, they agree with the standard notions of type and cotype. This allows  one to rule out the possibility of a bi-Lipschitz map $F$ between $\ell^p$ and $\ell^q$, $p\ne q$, without differentiating it.

Comment: Thanks,you just added a lot to me.If i may go further and kindly ask you to use a metric instead of norm the result would still be the same?

Comment: A norm induces a metric, to which the concept of Lipschitz maps refers.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: In addition: These spaces are homeomorphic (Mazur), which makes the example more interesting than two metric spaces of different cardinality.